# How to check if Windows Feature is installed and enabled with DISM.exe?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, dism

How to check if Windows Feature is installed and enabled with [DISM.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371719%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The command you are looking for is

```
dism /online /get-features
```

You can also use

```
dism /online /get-featureinfo /featurename:XXXXX
```

Where XXXXX is the name of the specific feature you are after. E.g TelnetServer

Don't forget to use an elevated command prompt with DISM.

Comment: Here's the relevant official documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/enable-or-disable-windows-features-using-dism#to-find-available-windows-features-in-an-image